# Deleting Pre-Packaged Tomcat WebApps

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I currently work on an excruciatingly slow remote machine and on Tomcat. So, I was wondering, Tomcat comes with some pre-packaged webapps like:

```
docs
examples
host-manager
manager
ROOT
```

Now I just wanted to know, can I delete `docs` and `examples` from the webapps folder without harming the server? I would assume that the other three webapps do serve some important purpose. All in all, if I do remove them, it will save me about 2.5 minutes on average every time I start the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can safely remove `docs`, `examples`, `host-manager` and `manager` if you don't use them.
2. The `ROOT` application is almost empty. Removing it entirely can cause some small bugs in some valves (e.g. `RewriteValve`), but you can replace it with an empty directory.

You should also consider other ways to [speed up Tomcat's start up](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/HowTo+FasterStartUp). If the server is a virtual server (without physical devices), entropy gathering might be a big problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I went over the guide partially till now. And I was able to get the time down a wee bit more by adding the `startStopThreads` as 0 on top of deleting the two webapps i mentioned.